# Blue screen after changing few components

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card, bsod

I bought a new PS with 550W corsair 550v, msi r7 370 armor core x2 graphic card (2gb 256 bits) and an fx 6300 processor.

I installed them in my new case.

After this I had some problems on Windows 10, my pc freezing after 5-10 mins from start.

I reinstalled OS (Windows 7) and now I got a bluescreen several times.

What should I do? I mention that I tested RAM, hard disk and the rest of the components.

[image]

Comment: As a general rule, when making changes, it's arguably better to change one thing at a time. That way, if weirdness ensues, you have a pretty good idea what caused it. That being said, video drivers can be notorious for causing blue screens. I'd suggest "falling back" to a known-good state, then proceed from there.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx looks like a CPU issue

Answer (score 0):

I have Asus M5A78L-M LX3 and new fx 6300 processor.I searched on the internet and as i see my motherboard(4 y.o) limits the voltage sent to CPU.The previous CPU was Athlon x2 3,5 MHz.The solution is to change with a new motherboard in my opinoin.Thx for answer!